Can i use defines from main.cpp in lib folder?
I wrote a little "library" to adress a external modul via UART.
So there is a xxx.h file and a xxx.c file. If i put those in the /include Folder and do a #include "xxx.h" everything works and it compiles.
If i put this files in the /lib folder, which is in my opinion the right place for them, ist is compiling but the compiler can't see #defines from the main.cpp. Is it somehow possible to use this defines in the library?
thanks
manuel
If i declare everything in the .h of the library it works - but it would be great to avoid this
